# AVRO Java generator - Dates generated as int

Tags: java, java-8, apache-kafka, avro, avro-tools

I'm using the maven plugin avro-maven-plugin (1.9.2) to generate Java classes from an AVRO-schema-file (avsc). I'm defining a date field as follows:

```
{
  "name": "inceptionDate",
  "type": "int",
  "logicalType": "date"
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, that it generates an **int** instead of a **Date** or **LocalDate**.

```
private int inceptionDate;
```

The pom.xml configuration is defined as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>schema</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <dateTimeLogicalTypeImplementation>JSR310</dateTimeLogicalTypeImplementation>
          <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/</sourceDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/</outputDirectory>
          <stringType>String</stringType>
          <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Any ideas, what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define the **date** field as follow:

```
{
  "name": "inceptionDate",
  "type": {
    "type": "int",
    "logicalType": "date"
  }
}
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/apache/avro/pull/309 it should be able to generate date classes. It was merged and released in 1.9.0. That's why there is a configuration option dateTimeLogicalTypeImplementation in the maven-plugin. Confusing...

Comment: You are right. See my update to the question. It should work.

Comment: Wow! This works!! Argh ...how was I not able to see it.